# Python in VSCode: Data in plot are not updating

Tags: python, plot

I want to plot data in loop to evoke a "live update" of new datas. But I get only one update of my plot and no other data are added to plot. What I am doing wrong?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

fig=plt.figure()
ax1=fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

x=[]
y=[]

for n in range(20):
    x.append(n)
    y.append(n*2)
    ax1.clear()
    ax1.scatter(x,y)
    #fig.canvas.draw()
    plt.autoscale(enable=True, axis='both')
    plt.show()

    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use [FuncAnimation](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation.html). This would be the implementation for your example -

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import time

fig=plt.figure()
ax1=fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

x=list(range(20))
y=[n*2 for n in x]

def animate(i):
    ax1.clear()
    ax1.scatter(x[:i],y[:i])
    plt.autoscale(enable=True, axis='both')

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=100)
plt.show()
```

### Update

In order to work with data that cannot be pre-computed in an array as shown above, you can use the frames argument of FuncAnimation as below -

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import time

fig=plt.figure()
ax1=fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

x=[]
y=[]

def frames():
    for i in range(20):
        yield i, i*2

def animate(args):
    ax1.clear()
    x.append(args[0])
    y.append(args[1])
    ax1.scatter(x, y)
    plt.autoscale(enable=True, axis='both')

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=frames, interval=100)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works fine, but little bit different then I expected.
 How can I update the X and Y values in time?
Because I do not know the X and Y data in advance (I read the data from serial port and I want to have live update).

Comment: @WITC Updated my answer. Hope it helps. You can pass a generator function to FuncAnimation as the frames argument which is then passed to the animate function.